# T-SQL - anti-duplicate trigger

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

I need to write a trigger which prevents from inserting more than one record at the same time and also checks if the place is already in the database. Code compiles but it doesn't work as it should - it displays error message even if I try to add a non-existing address

Here's my code:

```html
CREATE TRIGGER address_duplicate ON place
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @counter INT
 SELECT @counter=COUNT(*) FROM place WHERE street IN (SELECT street FROM inserted) AND number IN(SELECT number FROM inserted)
 AND city IN(SELECT city FROM inserted) AND postcode IN(SELECT postcode FROM inserted)
 IF @counter>0
 BEGIN
 RAISERROR('This record is already in the database',1,1)
 ROLLBACK
 END
 IF @@ROWCOUNT>1
 BEGIN
 RAISERROR('You can add only one record at the same time',1,2)
 ROLLBACK
 END
END
GO
```

Comment: It's not clear what the logic is that leads to this, but I'd have thought a unique index would be a whole lot easier than a trigger.

Comment: On duplicates then why not just add a unique constraint.    What does stopping  user from more than one insert in a statement solve.  They can just have multiple insert statements.

Comment: You probably want to check for duplicates on both `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. If you don't need a specific count of duplicates you should use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Join `inserted` with your data table (`place`) on your duplicate condition to handle multiple set operations (multiple rows) in the trigger. If any fail, they all fail.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic of identifying duplicate place is not correct.

Try something like this:

```
select @counter= count(*) from place p join inserted n
where p.address=n.address and p.city=n.city and p.postcode=n.postcode 
and p.number=n.number;
```

Also want you to know, using triggers to avoid duplicate can be very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd use a unique constraint and probably use TRY-CATCH when inserting, but if you really want to do it in a trigger, try this out:

```
CREATE TRIGGER address_duplicate ON place
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @newValue TABLE (ID INT);

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 1
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Insert cancelled. You can add only one record at the same time.',1,2);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO place
        OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @newValue
            SELECT *
            FROM inserted
            EXCEPT
            SELECT *
            FROM place
        IF (SELECT 1 FROM @newValue) IS NULL
            RAISERROR('Insert cancelled. This record is already in the database',1,1)
    END
END
```